# Cypress: Checking if the columns have the correct data

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, web-api-testing

I have created test case that gets all informations from table, in this table there is Users;
Name,
Role,
Status,
Last active statuses are listed, I select each line according to the user's id, I get the id information from the API before, I cannot assert them through the API because there are only "id","email" and " name" information, other information is not available.
How can I test that columns Role,Status, Last active status has the correct data? Thanks in advance for all the ideas.

Example of table;
**Name  |Email |               Roles   |   Status  | Last active**
*user00 |user00@mail.com    |  Doctor  |  Active   | 1 hour ago* 
*user01 |user01@mail.com    |  Engineer | Active    |2 minutes ago*
*user02 |user02@mail.com    |   Doctor   | Pending  | 2 months ago*
*user03 |user03@mail.com     | Police    |Inactive | 11 days ago**

**Example of html part ( [1]child element and [7] child element are not necessary to check)**

```
  <table>
     <tbody class="TableBody-root">
      <tr class="TableRow-root user_12341234blabla">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body width">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user00</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user00@mail.com</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Doctor</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Active</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">1 hour ago</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body stngs">
      </tr>
      <tr class="TableRow-root user_42241234alsbla">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body width">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user01</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user01@mail.com</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Engineer</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Active</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">2 minutes ago</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body stngs">
      </tr>
    <tr class="TableRow-root user_3554a234alsbla">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body width">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user02</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user02@mail.com</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Doctorr</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Pending</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">2 months ago</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body stngs">
      </tr>
    <tr class="TableRow-root user_87941234sasbla">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body width">
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user03</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">user03@mail.com</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Police</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">Inactive</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body">11 days ago</td>
       <td class"TableCell-root TableCell-body stngs">
      </tr>

   </tbody> 
</table>
```

**And this is my code;**

```
  cy.wait("@getUsers") 
 
      .its("response.body")
      .its("user")
      .then(user => {
  

        for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
          for (let a = 2; a <= 6; a++) {
            cy.get(`.user_${user[i].id}>:nth-child(${a})`)
              .invoke("text")
              .then(userInfo => {
                expect(userInfo).to.equal() // here i stuck
              });
          }
        }
```

```
**Its response.body**

    user    [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
    0   Object { id: "user_12341234blabla", name: "user00", email: "user00@mail.com", … }
    1   Object { id: "user_42241234alsbla", name: "user01", email: "user01@mail.com", … }
    2   Object { id: "user_3554a234alsbla", name: "user02", email: "user02@mail.com", … }

    3   Object { id: "user_87941234sasbla", name: "user03", email: "user03@mail.com", … }
    
    **Under the object [0]**
    
    id  "12341234blabla"
    name    "user00"
    email   "user00@mail.com"
    locale  "en"
    receive_notifications   true
    current_sign_in_at  "2022-06-14T00:36:41.240+02:00"
    created_at  "2022-02-10T10:25:45.333+01:00"
    updated_at  "2022-06-14T00:36:41.240+02:00"
    unconfirmed_email   null
    pending_reconfirmation  false
    confirmation_sent_at    null
    confirmation_period_expired null
    is_invited  false  //if its true it means status is pending otherwise active or inactive 
    is_managed_externally   false
    roles_without_context   [ {…} ]
    resource_role_users [ {…} ]
    invitee_invitations []
    
    **Under roles_without_context [{...}]**
    
    0   Object { id: "0a79-43ee-ae43", 
    created_at: "2022-02-10T10:25:45.345+01:00", 
    updated_at: "2022-02-10T10:25:45.345+01:00", … }
    id  "0a79-43ee-ae43"
    context_type    null
    context_id  null
    role    null
    created_at  "2022-02-10T10:25:45.345+01:00"
    updated_at  "2022-02-10T10:25:45.345+01:00"
    locked  true
    name    "Doctor"   //it shows role 
    clm_name    null
    client_id   "8506-d772d917af86"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the values you need to compare on the `user` object?

Check it out with `console.log(user)`, for example if `user` looks like

```js
[
  {
    id: "user00",
    email: "user00@mail.com",
    roles_without_context: {
      name: "Doctor"
    }
    status: "Active",
    lastSeen: "1 hour ago"
  },
  {
    id: "user01",
  ...
]
```

then in the test (roughly)

```js
const thisUser = user[i]

if (a === 2) {
  expect(userInfo).to.equal(thisUser.email)
} 
if (a === 3) {
  const role = user.roles_without_context.name
  expect(userInfo).to.equal(role)
} 
if (a === 4) {
  const status = thisUser.pending_reconfirmation ? 'Pending' : 'Active';
  expect(userInfo).to.equal(status)
} 
if (a === 5) {
  const lastSeen = thisUser.??? // what field is this
  expect(userInfo).to.equal(lastSeen)
}
```

Comment: You would need to define the other values in a variable. Hopefully you already know what the values *should* be?

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately i can only see for example on user object [0] user{ id:} , {name;} {email:}, but for roles maybe i can find under the selected object,  maybe under the object [0]                      roles_of_context: role:'Doctor', if it they so how can i use this?

Comment: I can be more specific if I see the `response.body`

Comment: Sure, I added response.body to my question

Comment: Thank you it's worked but in status part test is failed because its only expecting equality of Active , when row status is Inactive or pending it fails 

`if (a === 5) 
{
                const status = thisUser.pending_reconfirmation
                    ? "Pending" 
                     || "Inactive"   
                    : "Active";

                  expect(usersInfo).to.equal(status);
                } `   
 // i try to add `||` for `"Inactive"` but it fails

Comment: I took a guess at the most likely way to get `status` but really you should ask someone who knows the way the data is used to put text values on the web page. Same for `lastSeen`. I found a library that will help you translate dates into format like `2 minutes ago`, but you need to find out which data fields are applicable.